# Best way to import a package located in a sibling directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

My file stucture is :

```
top\
   my_package\
      __init__.py
      functions.py
   scripts\
      test.py
   main.py
```

I would like to import the content of `functions.py` in `test.py`.

In `main.py`, I can import `functions.py` with `from my_package.functions import ...`.
I was expecting to be able to import `functions.py` in `test.py` with something like `from ..my_package.functions import ...` but it raises the following error :

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

`top` directory shoudln't be a package because I want to be able to run `main.py` without being running a script in a package.

What is the proper/pythonic way import `functions.py` from `test.py` ?

I could add `my_package` to the PYTHONPATH, but my code would be less portable. I'm using Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because as far as python is concerned `my_package` and `scripts` directories are not related to each other. 
To solve your problem you can add `__init__.py` to your `top` directory and try using

```
from ..function import *
```

Comment: if I add an `__init__.py` file in my `top` directory, it will become a package, and running `main.py` would be running a script in a package which is not recommended. I edited my question to precise that `top` shouldn't be a package.